# how to distinguish two same name cookie variables which with different paths?

Tags: cookies

I am developing a website, `127.0.0.1/context/` is for front-end system, and `127.0.0.1/context/manager/` is for back-end system, and each one has its own `login` page, after logining successfully, I write cookie to browser separately, the two cookies have a same name variable `userId`, but their paths are `context` and `context/manager`, now I am accessing cookie in browser, but there are two `userId`s in `document.cookie`, and no `path` information in `cookie` to tell them apart, so how can I distinguish them?

Comment: You really shouldn't store the user id in a cookie.

Comment: @SamDufel, why? I store `userId` in cookie and show it in input, so that user don't need to type userId when s/he log in.

Comment: Anyone can edit their cookies to get access to any user account if the only authentication method is a cookie.

Comment: @SamDufel, I am using cookie + identifier ID(a generated unique number, stored in server) to do authentication. When user logs in, server writes cookie + identifier ID back, when user logins after some time, I use identifier ID to check if this user has logined before. Here I am just using cookie to remember userId, and show in page, so user don't need typing again.